# Connection timeout from SQL Server Management Studio 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2016

My SQL Server Management Studio when connecting to a database, disconnects me from the server I'm connected to after a few hours. My old installation of SSMS did not do this. This is not a problem on the database server as this is a new machine with a new installation of SSMS. My old machine does not time out my login. There must be a setting somewhere in SSMS. Does anyone know where it is?

Comment: Just to ask the obvious, but your machine doesn't go to sleep during that time? i.e. its not a OS setting which has changed?

Comment: @DaleBurrell my machine sleeps, but this was never an issue before on my old machine as that would sleep as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Management Studio disconnected after a period of inactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729023/sql-server-management-studio-disconnected-after-a-period-of-inactivity)

Comment: @DaleBurrell  i think the issue was my computer was sleeping, just checked the pwoer settings on my old machine and its not set to sleep. thanks for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your power settings as if your machine goes into a low power mode it may drop network connections.