# How to keep a Winforms application installed in various PCs always connected to a database in SQL server express

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-express

I have created a Winforms application and I installed it on 6 different PCs within the same network. However, everything works fine for the most part, but sometimes all of a sudden, they stop communicating with the SQL server. The exception the application throws is ErrorSystem.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A Network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.

I've already made changes to the firewall settings to allow the sqlserver.exe and the sqlserverexpress.exe and the sqlserverbrowser.exe and the .exe for the application. I've also configured it to allow the port number to listen through the firewall. But all those changes I've done on the local PC that's hosting the SQL server and not on each individual PC that's got the winforms app installed. The SQL server it's not being hosted on an actual server. But I make sure the PC stays always on. I don't know what else to do. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Management Studio disconnected after a period of inactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729023/sql-server-management-studio-disconnected-after-a-period-of-inactivity)

Comment: Do all 6 stop at same time or is it random?  I'm guessing it is random.  My suspicion are with the DNS Password server, but this is a wild guess.  Do you see any errors in the SQL Server logs?  Do you see any errors in the Windows Event Viewer on any of the machines?

Comment: I would say, there is no point in keeping a connection open for longer than needed. particularly if it is SQL Express on a normal PC. I agree with @Mark. Keeping connections open does block resources not only on the server but also on the client

Comment: jdweng For the most part all the PCs stop connecting to the SQL server database at the same time, and most of the time the all re-establish connection at the same time. Except for today, today I have all back running except for one of them.

Comment: jdweng Yes the SQL Server Logs for this morning when the issue happened it logged a few errors.

Comment: jdweng some of the errors are: SQL Trace was stopped due to server shutdown. Trace ID = "1", SQL Server shutdown has been initiated, .NET Framework runtime has been stopped, Service Broker manager has shut down, SQL Server is terminating in response to a "stop" request from Service Control Manager, The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name(SPN)

Comment: One other thing, and I don't know if this even matters. All 6 of those PCs have the same Windows user name and password.

Comment: @Yorelis, You can plainly see from the logs that your "server" machine is restarting: "server shutdown". Now you need to keep reading the logs until you find the actual shutdown event, which should tell you what/who activated it (my bet is on windows update/company policy updates etc.). I suspect that your 'client" machines will do the same as well.